# How to set fields value in Views PHP module?

Tags: 7, views

How to define the fields value in Views PHP [module](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to load the node

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
```

then you can either access

```
$value=$node->field_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

or assign

```
$node->field_time['und'][0]['value'] = $value
```

values to the node items. You may need to print out the content of the `$node` object to see the actual field_name

```
$node_r = print_r($node, true);
watchdog('NODE PRINT OUT', "$node_r");
```

then view it in the recent log mesages

```
admin/reports/dblog
```

Ensure the DBlog (Database logging) core module is enabled

Comment: Thanks, but can the $row->php value be defined in such way?( So it can be called in another field or filter )

Comment: Don't forget `node_save($node);`